MUI Toolpad core Dashboard Layout content cannot fill up all available space
I am using the MUI Toolpad core Dashboard Layout for my frontend, but I am not able to fully utilize all the available space on the content side.
I am using the demo code form the tutorial here:
https://mui.com/toolpad/core/react-dashboard-layout/.
Here is the basic structure of my DashboardLayout.
<AppProvider
      navigation={NAVIGATION}
      router={router}
      theme={demoTheme}
      window={demoWindow}
    >
      <DashboardLayout>
        <DemoPageContent pathname={pathname} />
      </DashboardLayout>
    </AppProvider>

And edit the DemoPageContent to show a Box of MUI.
function DemoPageContent({ pathname }: { pathname: string }) {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        width: "100%", // Full width of the viewport
        height: "100%", // Full height of the viewport
        overflow: "hidden", // Avoid scrollbars
        backgroundColor: "blue", // Change to your desired color
        display: "flex",
        flexGrow: 1,
      }}
    >
      This {pathname} div takes all available space!
    </Box>
  );
}

And here is my result.
[Here is my result] (https://i.sstatic.net/MlaqYnpB.png)
The version of mui and toolpad core I am using:
"@mui/icons-material": "^6.1.3",
"@mui/material": "^6.1.3",
"@toolpad/core": "^0.7.0",


